# Quotas and limits for App Attest and device check in firebase for iOS per day or per device?

Tags: ios, firebase-app-check, devicecheck

what is the Quotas and limits for App Attest and device check in firebase for iOS per day or per device?

How many api calls is allowed per day or per device per day ?